# Conditions for $o(|u|^{-1})$ decay of the Fourier transform of a bounded variation function

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, bounded-variation

As the question suggests I am looking for a (not very restrictive) condition on a function of bounded variation so that its Fourier transform is $o(|u|^{-1})$ as $|u| \to \infty$. Let me elaborate on my actual question:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded, integrable (i.e. from $L^1(\mathbb{R})$) and of bounded variation. Then, by basic Fourier analysis, $|\mathcal{F}[f](u)|=O( |u|^{-1})$ as $|u|\to \infty$, where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}[f](u):= \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{iux}f(x)dx.
\end{equation}
My question is, are there any not very restrictive conditions we can put on $f$ so that not only the above is true but furthermore $|\mathcal{F}[f](u)|=o(|u|^{-1})$ as $|u|\to \infty$?

The function I am dealing with is, essentially, of the form $f(x)=e^{-|x|}-g(x)$, where $g$ is non-negative, it is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for any $p\in [1,\infty]$, is such that $\lim_{|x|\to 0} g(x)=1$ and it is unimodal at $0$ (i.e. it is non-increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and non-decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^-$). Hence $f$ satisfies the assumptions above and also $\lim_{|x|\to 0} f(x)=0$.

This last property of $f$ seems to be crucial  to obtain the $o(|u|^{-1})$ decay in the Fourier transform because
\begin{align}
\lim_{|u|\to \infty} |u\mathcal{F}[f](u)|= | \, lim_{|u|\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{iy}f(y/u)dy \, |= | \, lim_{|x|\to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{iy}f(xy)dy \, |.
\end{align}

The dominated and the monotone convergence theorems can be used to impose fairly general conditions on $f$ to obtain the aforementioned conclusion, but these conditions are too restrictive if we look at the form of my function $f$. Any thoughts on other conditions on $g$ such that the above display is zero? I suppose asking $g$ to have a $(1+\epsilon)$-weak derivative ($\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small) would be enough, but doesn't my function $g$ have enough structure to imply the desired decay on the Fourier transform of $f$?

Comment: I also know that there exist constants $C>1$ and $\delta>0$ (small) such that $g(x)< C\,  (1+|x|)^{-1-\delta}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but I have not been able to use this.

Comment: Is it big $O$ or small $o$?

Comment: Which of them? They all seem to be right to me.

Answer (score 3):

A jump discontinuity contributes a term that is not $o(|u|^{-1})$. Indeed, suppose that $f$ is absolutely continuous except for a jump discontinuity at $x=a$. Then the distributional derivative $f'$ consists of an $L^1$ function plus a multiple of $\delta_a$. The transform of an $L^1$ function is $o(1)$ at infinity, but the transform of $\delta_a$ is $e^{-ia u}$  (up to normalizations). Hence, $|\hat{f'}(u)|$ has a nonzero limit at infinity, which implies that $|u|\,|\hat f(u)|$ has a nonzero limit at infinity.

On the other hand, if your function is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) (in addition to being BV), then its Fourier transform is $o(|u|^{-1})$. Indeed, absolute continuity implies that $f$ is an antiderivative of a locally integrable function $g$, and $\int|g|$ is the total variation of $f$ (hence, $g\in L^1$). By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, $\widehat g(u)=o(1)$ as $u\to\infty$. Hence, $|\widehat f(u) |=\frac{1}{|u|}|\widehat g(u)| = o(|u|^{-1})$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Your are right, absolute continuity gives a sufficient condition, but is too strong for my setting (see functions $f$ and $g$ above).

Comment: Perhaps I am more interested in your comment about the jump discontinuity. Are you saying that if there is at least one jump discontinuity (finite jump I understand, anywhere in the real line), then the decay is necessarily of rate $|u|^{-1}$? When I wrote the question above I thought having no discontinuity at the origin (and taking value 0 at it) plus something else could be enough, regardless of the jump discontinuities at other points.

Comment: But, heuristically, a jump discontinuity contributes with a Dirac's delta to the distributional derivative, and this is integrable (hence BV) but cannot be differentiated anymore while keeping the integrability, correct?

Comment: @Coca See my update. A jump discontinuity at a point $a\ne 0$ is just as bad as a discontinuity at $0$. And yes, the reason is that the derivative picks up a Dirac delta, which has a Fourier transform of constant modulus.