# Fourier transform of absolute continous function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform, bounded-variation

I was reading an answer (the only one so far) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538178/conditions-for-ou-1-decay-of-the-fourier-transform-of-a-bounded-variati/542241#542241).

I am wondering about the following statement:

$f$ is absolute continous and of bounded variation (hence has an antidrivative $g$), $f$ has total variation of $\int |g| dx<\infty$ (and hence $g$ is in $L^1$). That's all clear so far.

Then one can apply the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma and show
$$
\widehat g(u)=o(1)
$$

but **how** do we can conclude this statement:

$$|\widehat f(u) |=\frac{1}{|u|}|\widehat g(u)| = o(|u|^{-1})$$

The second equality is clear, but the first one stays a mystery to me. Any insights?

Comment: $f$ **is** a primitive of an $L^1$ function $g$, not "has". Basically, it's integration by parts of the Fourier integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah ofc...thanks, i was missing that. Now everything works out.